# What happens to excess data given by the user?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

In C++, what happens to excess input, if it is given? Does it get stored somewhere or is completely ignored?

For example, this sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   char a, b, c;

   cout << "Enter three letters: ";

   cin.get(a).get(b).get(c);

   cout << "a: " << a << "\nb: " << b << "\nc: " << c << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Which just asks for three letters, will let me type in as many as I want. Where do all the rest go? Preferably nowhere... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They go into an input buffer. When your process exits (without reading them) the buffer is discarded (and the unread contents along with it).

Comment: Wow, cool, thanks for the fast response! I'm still going to have to try and look into that to make sure they never get read under any circumstances... unless you can confirm that for me?

Edit: so fast I can't even accept it yet!

Comment: I don't know of anything that could give absolute confirmation of it for every possible operating system, but I don't know of (and can hardly imagine) an OS where it was otherwise either.

Comment: @rofls: they (probably) don't get read if *you* do not read them. If however a latter part of your function tries to read from `cout`, then it will first have to read the garbage.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: minor typo: you undoubtedly meant `cin` instead of `cout`.

Comment: Wow, is there a way to clear that out, just in case you wanted to prevent that from happening? I'm sure you could also just limit the size of the input... right?

Comment: I feel like two dragons are fighting and I'm watching... sorry, I'm spending too much time on Reddit lately. I would like to see this sorted out though; I thought cout made sense :/

Edit: ok, all is well.

Comment: @rofls: you can use [`std::istream::ignore`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/). Note that it stops at the `delim` character provided.

Comment: In case you're wondering about the difference: `std::istream::flush()` will throw away whatever the input buffer currently holds -- no matter how little, how much, or what it is. `std::istream::ignore()` will remove data from the buffer up to a specified maximum, or until it reaches a specified delimiter (whichever comes first).

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to read about that... This website is the best! You both rock!

Edit: but I'm still a little confused about how the delimiter would be implemented in practice, with user input.

Comment: @JerryCoffin `std::cin.flush()` doesn't have any standard defined meaning---it is implementation defined.  (Logically, given the name, I would expect it to be a no-op.)  And `std::istream::ignore()` will remove characters from  the stream---whether they are already in the buffer or not, which may provoke another read to the system.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.  There are several buffers in action.  *Typically* (nothing
guaranteed, but certainly the case for Unix and Windows), you'll have to
press enter before your program sees any data; everything you've typed
up to and including enter then goes into a buffer in your process, which
is then discarded when the process terminates.

This is the default behavior, supposing that your process was started
from the command line of a shell, and that standard input is connected
to the keyboard.  If another process has started your process, it may
have reconfigured the input to behave differently; it's quite possible
to configure the keyboard (at least under Unix) to send each character
as it is entered, in which case, the next process to read the keyboard
after you've read it will get the extra characters.

Finally, if standard input is from a file, of course, the data in the
file stays where it is, as you'ld expect.  If it is from a pipe, at
least on Unix, the data will be discarded, and any processes still
writing to the pipe will receive a signal.